# ES6 e addEventListener(). Por que esse método não aceita referência de uma função anônima?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Por que o 'click' não é invocado?

```
$elemento.addEventListener('click', click, true);
var click = () => { ... };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve declarar a variável com sua função antes de tentar usar ela...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var click = () => {
    alert("Clicou");
  };
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", click, true);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" id="test">
```

Comment: Entendi. Porém eu achava que ao declarar a variável que armazena a função anônima com var, ela seria de escopo global sendo acessado de qualquer parte de código mesmo sendo declarada antes do uso. Obrigado